# Uninstalling a program of many computers efficiently

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a PowerShell that would uninstall a program from remote computers but it takes a long time since it goes through all the computers in the list. I just need help from you to modify it so it first checks if the program exists on the remote computer or not and then uninstalls it:

```powershell
$comps = gc "C:\Computers.txt"
$appname = gc "C:\appname.txt"
foreach($comp in $comps){
   foreach ($appname in $appname){
      $prod=gwmi -computer $comp win32_product  | ?{$_.name -eq "$appname"}
      $prod.uninstall()
   }
}
```

Comment: Just run WMI query and uninstall for each computer in parallel as jobs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! thanks

```
$comps= gc "C:\Computers.txt"
$appname = gc "C:\appname.txt"
foreach($comp in $comps){
$program = gwmi -computer $comp Win32_Product | sort-object Name | select Name | where { $_.Name -match “$appname”}
if($program -eq $null)
{
 Write-host "Does Not"
}
else
{
$prod=gwmi -computer $comp win32_product  | ?{$_.name -eq "$appname"}
$prod.uninstall()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `foreach –parallel` instead of just `foreach`. Official docs [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713711.aspx).

```
workflow uninstallstuff {
    sequence {
        $comps = gc "C:\Computers.txt"
        $appname = gc "C:\appname.txt"
        foreach -parallel ($comp in $comps){
            foreach ($appname in $appname){
                $prod=gwmi -computer $comp win32_product  | ?{$_.name -eq "$appname"}
                $prod.uninstall()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should run each computer in parallel but each app for that computer will be uninstalled sequentially.

edit: rewrote as a workflow. I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: I might be wrong but in what you linked _ForEach -Parallel is valid only in a Windows PowerShell    
    Workflow._ Which you do not have here

Comment: I'll have to check later if that actually works, but it should be able to be invoked directly as `uninstallstuff`.

Comment: Just FYI : the win32_product class is kinda broken and forces a repair on all registered msi applications. Thats the reason why it's so slow to query that class. Check the application eventlog on your target machine after querying this class